# Расположение TextView под другим элементом в RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, textview

Имеется следующая xml разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/note_icon"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/play"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/prev" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/play" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/play"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/next" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/curTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/seekBar"
            android:text="@string/_0_00"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Проблема в следующем - при `TextView`, находящимся над `SeekBar` все отображается как надо, но если расположить `TextView` под `SeekBar`, то `TextView` улетает куда-то вниз и его не видно даже. В чем проблема?

**UPD**

Поубирал везде `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` и немного изменил разметку. Теперь она выглядит так:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/note_icon"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev"
            android:layout_below="@id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/play"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
            android:text="@string/prev" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_below="@id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
            android:text="@string/play" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/play"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
            android:layout_below="@id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/next" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/play"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/curTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/seekBar"
            android:text="@string/_0_00"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Однако теперь обратная проблема - под `SeekBar` текст располагается нормально, а если установить над ним - улетает на уровень кнопок.

Comment: Проблема в `alignParentBottom=true` для `Seekbar`

Comment: @Jarvis_J, обновил вопрос

Comment: теперь это из-за `marginTop` в `SeekBar`'е. Определитесь, что вы хотите - текст сверху (тогда `SeekBar` `alignParentBottom`) или снизу (тогда текст `alignParentBottom`, а `SeekBar` - `above`)

Comment: @Jarvis_J, понял, просто ожидал одинакового поведения как под, так и над. Спасибо. Оформите как ответ?

Comment: Тут два вопроса на внимательность) не вижу смысла